# Tabela dinâmica com PHP

Tags: php

Estou criando uma tabela dinâmica usando PHP.

O problema e o seguinte criei um campo para modificar os valores da variável `$conteudo` do corpo da tabela porem não consigo mudar mais de um campo da tabela alguém ai pode me ajudar a resolver este problema?

PS. para passar o campo a ser modificado e da seguinte maneira (campo1,campo2,campo3)

```
<?php

/*
 * CABEÇALHO DA TABELA
 */
$campos = explode(',','id,nome,idade,sexo');
$conteudo = explode(',','1,funano,21,1');


/*
 * MODIFICADOR DE CAMPOS
 */
$modificador = explode(',','21');



echo '<table border="1px" width="100%">';
echo '<tr>';

foreach($campos as $x){
            echo '<th>'.$x.'</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';



/**
 * CONTEUDO DA TABELA
 */
echo '<tr>';
foreach($conteudo as $b){
    /*
     * COMPARANDO O MODIFICADOR COM O CAMPO DA TABELA
     */
    foreach($modificador as $m) {


        if ($b == $m) {
            echo '<th>' . 'campo' . '</th>';
        } else {
            echo '<td>'.$b.'</td>';
        }
    }
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

O problema acontece quando tento acrescentar mais um campo para modificar como por exemplo:

`$modificador = explode(',','21,funano');`

Comment: explica mais o que você tentou ... pelo que vejo nos comentários quem fez sabe bem o que tem ali

Comment: roda o script que você vai entender melhor

Comment: explica melhor o que tu precisa e o que tu tentou para ficar mais claro

Comment: Só consegue mudar um campo, porque só esta a usar um campo no modificador, aqui funciona direito: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/n7ri-zas8

Comment: Jorge B tenta acrescentar mais um campo $modificador = explode(',','21,fulano'); e veja o que vai acontecer com a tabela

Comment: Ai tu comparas "21" do `$m` com "21" do `$b` e quando isso acontece ele substitui o "21" por "campo".

Comment: perfeito agora a bronca e tentar compara mais de um campo da tabela quando tento isso a tabela fica toda bugada

Comment: Isso é porque imprimes sempre ou campo ou o valor sempre que comparas.

Comment: E como e que resolver este empasse?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18196/discussion-between-alexandre-sousa-and-jorge-b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que estas a imprimir o **valor do campo** ou o **modificador** sempre que verificas todos os `$m` e acaba por imprimir mais que uma vez por cada campo.

Podes verificar quando houver *match* de `$m` com `$b` se já foi imprimido:

```
foreach($conteudo as $b){
    /*
     * COMPARANDO O MODIFICADOR COM O CAMPO DA TABELA
     */
    $isEqual = false;
    foreach($modificador as $m) {

        if ($b == $m) {
            echo '<th>' . 'campo' . '</th>';
            $isEqual = true; // se forem iguais imprime campo
        }
    }
    if(!$isEqual) echo '<td>'.$b.'</td>';//senão imprime o valor de $b
}
```

[phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3d0h-kupy)

Ou podes usar a função [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) do PHP que compara se um elemento está no `array`:

```
foreach($conteudo as $b){
    /*
     * COMPARANDO O MODIFICADOR COM O CAMPO DA TABELA
     */
    if (in_array($b, $modificador))
        echo '<th>' . 'campo' . '</th>';
    else
        echo '<td>'.$b.'</td>';
}
```

Comment: Consegui resolver todos os problemas com a ajudar obrigado a todos que disponibilizaram o vosso tempo